# Object has no attribute '__bases__' when calling inspect.getmro()

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance, apache-storm

I have a python class that inherits from [storm.py](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-multilang/python/src/main/resources/resources/storm.py) from the Apache Storm MultiLang project.

My class looks like the following:

```
import storm
class MyClassName(Storm.Bolt):
def initialize(self,conf,context):
     self._conf = conf;
     self._context = context
def process(self, in_tuple):
     storm.ack(in_tuple)
if __name__ == '__main__':
     MyClassName().run()
```

I copied my python file (myfilename.py) out to /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-package.  I then logged into the python shell and did an `import myfilename`.  That completed without error.  When I run the following `inspect.getmro(myfilename.MyClassName())` I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'MyClassName' object has no attribute '__bases__'
```

I was under the impression that when I declared my class and passed it `Storm.Bolt` that I was extending `Storm.Bolt`.  My questions are:

- Do I need to define `__bases__` in my class?
- What else am I missing?

Using Python 2.7.13 on CentOs7.  Storm version is 1.1.0

Comment: I believe it is a new-style class as it inherits from object.  I put the wrong link up before for storm.py.  Source should be there now.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inspect.getmro` function expects its argument to be a class, but you're passing it an instance. Get rid of the parentheses that call the class and your code should work:

```
inspect.getmro(myfilename.MyClassName) # not MyClassName()!
```

If the call you gave in the question was a simplified example and you don't have the class directly available where you're calling `getmro` on the instance, you can use `type` to get the class:

```
obj = SomeClass()  # this happens somewhere earlier on, and we don't know SomeClass below

inspect.getmro(type(obj))   # but we can easily get it using type()
```